# Animation in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to do a simple animation. I just want to animate a rectangle. I found the following code

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Height="56" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,104,0,0" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Fill="#FFFA0000" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,276,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="rotate" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
private void rotate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
     da.From = 0;
     da.To = 360;
     da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
     da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
     RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
     rectangle1.RenderTransform = rt;
     rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
}
```

It works perfectly, but I need to change it for the MVVM architecture. Note the element "rectangle1". How do I use this element in MVVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it typically inappropriate to use an MVVM approach for this sort of thing.  The animation of a specific UI element is (almost always) *view-specific code*.  It is specific to a single view design, and may not be applicable to other views that bind to the same view model.  Doing this in the view's code behind is perfectly acceptable, and probably the best approach.